# Proper practise to pulling upstream changes from generated-code

Tags: git, code-generation, yeoman

this is normally the workflow....after forking, i can usually update my codebase via

```
git remote add upstream <PATH>
git pull upstream master
```

then, recently i learn about code generators (specifically yeoman). they seem wonderful, but is there anyway to update my code when a new version of the generator is out? what should the workflow be?

I was thinking to get new version of code generator, re-generate the code in different folder, git init, add it as a remote to codebase i was working on, then merge.

Thanks in advance for anyone who might have any insight on this!!

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding what Yeoman does, but why not just run the tool in whatever checked out copy you have of your project and commit the resulting changes?

Answer (score 1):

just tried what Magnus suggested. works very nicely!

yeoman doesn't allow "merge conflict" editing when code is generated (only allows Yes or No for overwrite).
but if i just overwrite everything, i can certainly compare current working files to most recent commit. then i make changes accordingly.

thanks!!